# Formatting a get/return that has a formula in it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm a little stumped on how I would go about formatting the below get/return so that there are only 2 digits after the decimal, any help is much appreciated.

```
public decimal? aExample { get; set; }
public decimal? bExample { get; set; }

public decimal? Combined
{
    get { return aExample / bExample; }
}

[Display(Name = @"ABC %")]
public decimal? Combined => aExample.NullableDivide(bExample);
```

Comment: You could just use rounding.  But this looks more like a string formatting issue to me, also implied by the title, which should be handled by whatever is bound to `Combined`.

Comment: As you have nullable Decimals, then you should also add checks to ensure that they are not null before you attempt a division.  And of course you should also check that you don't attempt a zero division.

Comment: Be very careful about the difference between rounding a mathematical value itself, or formatting the _display_ of a mathematical value. It is unclear which of the two you need, but (to me) this intuitively feels like you need the latter (i.e. string formatting).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Math.Round()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-5.0#System_Math_Round_System_Decimal_) function,

```
//Important: This will loose precision of result. It will round value to its closed value
public decimal? Combined
{
    get { 
        return aExample == null || bExample == null ? 
            null
            : Math.Round((aExample / bExample) ?? default(decimal), 2);  //Return result with 2 precision.
    }
}
```

Try Online: [.NET FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jGsZRh)

Comment: Thanks for your solution and help @Prasad Telkikar, but I did end up applying an update as I was receiving an alert regarding issues converting decimal? to decimal. Please review my update solution, a revision to your original post

Comment: //Important: This will loose precision of result. It will round value to its closed value
public decimal? Combined
    {
        get { 
                return aExample == null || bExample == null ? 
                        null
                        : Math.Round(aExample / bExample??2);  //Return result with 2 precision.
            }
    }

Comment: `Math.Round(aExample / bExample??2);` If you are doing this one, then this solution will not help you to solve decimal? to decima error. `??` is a [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator). It will return 2 if the result of division is null.

Comment: @user7879707, did you check my latest updated answer. Hope it will help you